# List of users gets divided into individual characters in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi, tweepy

I've written a bit of code for my Raspberry Pi to get all the people a twitter user is following, convert that to a list and have that list populate a CSV file. I have mostly reached my objective, but my problem is now that python puts each character of the followed users' screen names in a separate column! I have been googling it for an hour now but I feel I'm lacking the right search terms!

Here are the relevant parts of the code I wrote:

```
userList = []

while True:
    try:
        user = next(users)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('Twitter request restriction: within less than 15min of last request')
        time.sleep(60*15)
        user = next(users)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    userList.append(user.screen_name)

resultFile = open(filename,'wb')

wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')

for item in userList:
    wr.writerow(item)
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot of CSV file]

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong here, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi Gwenn and welcome to Stackoverflow! Great first post, by the way. What are you aiming for? I guess, one user output per line, is that correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks! yes, that's right: one user output per line. The csv output will be used in IBM's i2 Analyst's Notebook in order to create network maps!

Answer (score 1):

`writerow()` takes an iterable and writes each element of that iterable as a CSV "cell". You're passing a string to it, and that string iterates over its characters - therefore you get one character per cell.

Just place the string inside a list:

```
for item in userList:
    wr.writerow([item])
```

---

<sup>Strictly speaking (and unless your user names might contain special characters like quotes or commas), you don't really need to use the `csv` module since your file only has one column, so there is nothing to be separated by commas</sup>